# Websocket or Firecloud Store for Real-time Notifications

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, real-time-updates

I just want to know which one is better for real-time notifications either Web Sockets or Cloud Firestore. Actually, I'm doing BS(SE) and as a final year project, I'm developing a system in which the mobile app and website would be synced. The scenario for notifications is that if a user will send a report from the mobile app, it will be notified to the website at the same time that will be used by the admin. I'm using PHP for APIs to perform CRUD operations in the MySQL database. I searched about real-time notifications so I found these 2 options, what would be the better one, I'm quite confused about both as I'm a student and I don't have much idea. However, if I use Cloud Firestore so according to my knowledge after searching is that I only need to copy the report table from my MYSQL db to Cloud Firestore and if any change will be occurred in the report table in my primary database then a triggering function will be called to perform real-time notifications to the website. Also if any other ideas regardless of both so please share. If the cloud Firestore is better then tell me about its setup with PHP files and Android so it's easy for me to get started with it.